# How to avoid instantiating an object every single time so I can add objects to a list of objects contained within that first object?

Tags: c#, .net

Each time I click on a button I would like to add a new location via the AddLocation method to a list of LocationSpecs objects. But with the code as is, a new officeRental object is created every time I click on the btnAddLocation button with a new list of LocationSpecs objects. So every time I click on the button the previous object is lost from memory. How can I modify this code so in the end I can have only one list of LocationSpecs objects inside a single officeRental object?

> ```
>    private void btnAddLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>    {
>        string name = txtName.Text;
>        string neighborhood = txtNeighborhood.Text;
>        LocationSpecs location = new LocationSpecs(name, neighborhood);
>        OfficeRental officeRental = new OfficeRental();
>        officeRental.AddLocation(location);
>        MessageBox.Show(name + " in " + neighborhood + " added.");
>    }
> ```

> ```
>   public class OfficeRental : IOfficeRental
>   {
>    public List<LocationSpecs> LocationSpecs { get; set; }
>    public OfficeRental()
>    {
>        LocationSpecs = new List<LocationSpecs>();
>
>    }
>    public void AddLocation(LocationSpecs locationSpecs)
>    {
>        // throw new NotImplementedException();
>        LocationSpecs.Add(locationSpecs);
>    }
> ```

> ```
>  public class LocationSpecs
>  {
>    public string Name { get; }
>    public string Neighborhood { get; }
>
>    public LocationSpecs(string name, string neighborhood)
>    {
>        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));
>        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(neighborhood)) throw new >ArgumentException(nameof(neighborhood));
>
>        Name = name;
>        Neighborhood = neighborhood;
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: `Every time I click on the button the previous object is lost from memory.` -- Why?  They're in your `LocationSpecs` list.  BTW, your LocationSpecs class?  Just call it `Location` or `LocationSpec`.  Don't give it the same name as your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the line:

> OfficeRental officeRental = new OfficeRental();

from the button click function and make it a Class member variable, similar to:

```
class <yourFormName>
{
    OfficeRental officeRental = new OfficeRental();
    ... // the rest of your code
}
```

This will mean that the `officeRental` object is now visible throughout the whole class (a class member variable) instead of just being used in the single button click handler.